# arbitrary graph has a n matching or an independent set having size at least |G|-2n+1

Tags: graph-theory

I am considering the problem: arbitrary graph has a n matching or an independent set having size at least |G|-2n+1.

Could someone please show some ideas or outlines so that I can think about the details?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that by "a $n$ matching" you mean a matching of size $n$, i.e., a set of $n$ vertex-disjoint edges in $G$. And I'm guessing that by $|G|$ you mean $|V(G)|$, the number of vertices in $G$. Right?

It seems to me that your result "at least $|V(G)|-2n+1$ could be improved to "at least $|V(G)|-2n+2$" but I could be wrong, you'd better check this carefully.

I would approach the problem by considering a **maximal** matching. I would assume that the size of the matching is **less** than $n$, so it consists of $m$ edges where $m\lt n$, i.e., $m\le n-1$. Then I would consider the set of vertices **not** covered by the matching, call it $S$; I would try to show that $S$ is independent and contains at least the required number of vertices.

Comment: haha, you're right about the notations. i'll be more careful next time. thanks for your hint! i'll work on it.